# wso2 esb mtom attachment

Tags: proxy, wso2, mtom, wso2-esb

I am currently playing around with the WSO2 enterprise service bus, some cxf based webservices and mtom attachments.

Using SoapUI (MTOM enabled), I submit the following request to one backend service:

```
     ...
     <incident>
         ....
        <attachmentList>
           <attachment>
              <contentID>cid:soapui32.png</contentID>
           </attachment>
        </attachmentList>   
     </incident>
     ...
```

With MTOM enabled Raw data is

```
    ...
    <attachmentList>
       <attachment>
         <contentID>
          <inc:Include href="cid:soapui32.png" xmlns:inc="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/>
         </contentID>
       </attachment>
    </attachmentList>
    ...

    ------=_Part_0_22113723.1360006252844
    Content-Type: image/x-png; name=soapui32.png
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
    Content-ID: <soapui32.png>
    Content-Disposition: attachment; name="soapui32.png"; filename="soapui32.png"
    ......
```

---

So far, so good.
Now, as the next step, I create a WSDL based proxy service (WSO2 ESB 4.5.1) for this webservice.

```
    <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="testService" transports="https,http" statistics="enable" trace="enable" startOnLoad="true">
     <target>
      <outSequence>
       <send/>
     </outSequence>
     <endpoint>
      <wsdl service="IncidentService" port="IncidentServicePort" uri="uri2myservicewsdl"/>
     </endpoint>
     </target>
     <publishWSDL uri="uri2myservicewsdl"/>
     <description></description>
    </proxy>
```

enableMTOM is set to true in the axis2.xml, MTOM is enabled for the proxy service.

If I submit exactly the same request with the same attachment via SoapUI, the esb transforms the attachment to inline content (debug log):

```
    DEBUG -  Starting Activation Handler invocation. Incoming Message: 
    ......
     <incident>
        <attachmentList>
           <attachment>
              <contentID>iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh.....</contentID>
           </attachment>
        </attachmentList>   
     </incident>
    .....
    </soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
    {org.wso2.carbon.activation.module.ActivationHandler}
```

Where can I enable MTOM, so that the proxy doesnt transform it to inline content?

Many thanks in advance.

### Workaround

Maybe someone is interested, even if it's just a workaround:

I had enabled MTOM and SwA attachments in the axis2.xml (wso2 esb conf directory).

As soon as I disabled SwA and only left MTOM enabled, attachments are not transformed to inline content any more.

Now SwA is disabled for all proxy services, but that's ok for the moment.
I will have another look at it later, maybe it's a bug.